# Get the drive letter from device handle in C#

Tags: c#, windows, events

I'm working in a small tool to log activity in USB devices.
My tool works as a windows service catching all the device events, basically I'm starting to monitor the USB device as soon I catch a `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` event. After this, I need to stop the monitor as soon I get the `DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE` (otherwise my service will deny the device to be safe ejected). The problem is that the tool should be able to monitor several number of devices, so I need to be able to determine which device is the user trying to eject. 
I found out that the `DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE` event carries a [`DEV_BROADCAST_HANDLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure. I'm trying to extract some useful information from this structure that can allow me to identify which device is being ejected. I found out that there is a handle to the device, I tried to extract the drive letter using the system function [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but is not working properly (returning empty value).
Any idea how can I do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @MSalters My question is a specific question, is not included in the question stated in your comment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer seems to be a bit less obvious than I thought: Call `RegisterDeviceNotification` for each device you're interested in, identifying the device by its handle. Since YOU create the registration, you'll know which drive letter maps to which notification handle.

Comment: I guess use that function via [pinvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/RegisterDeviceNotification.html)?

Comment: @Default: There's no other way, I think. The native API of Windows is still C-based.